# LINQ filter list based on property value and filter the properties as well

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, ef-database-first

My `NavigationItem` has navigation property `NavigationItemsPermissions` where I have `RoleId`. As input parameter in function I have `List<int> roleIds` where I will have something like {1, 3}.

How do I finish my `LINQ` to give me back `NavigationItem`(s) that has `NavigationItemsPermissions` with *some* `RoleId` on the input list. **Note** that, additionally, I want only those `NavigationItemsPermissions` with `RoleId` from the input list.

Here is where I'm stuck at

```
public List<NavigationItem> GetNavigationItems(MenuType menuType, List<int> roleIds)
{
    var navigationItems = DbContext.NavigationItems.Where(x => x.MenuTypeId == (int) menuType && !x.IsDeleted && x.NavigationItemsPermissions.Any(r=>r.RoleId **in roleIds**)));       

    return navigationItems;
}
```

To give a simpler analogy (not real data), if there is a list of developers

```
developers: [
    { name: "Hickory", skills: ["c#", "js", "linq"] }
    { name: "Dickory", skills: ["html", "css", "js"] }
    { name: "Dock", skills: ["html", "c#", "oracle"] }
]
```

And a given list of skills `list = [ "c#", "linq" ]`, I want the following as result

```
[{ name: "Hickory", skills: ["c#", "linq"] }
{ name: "Dock", skills: ["c#"] }]
```

Sample real data:

[image]

[image]

Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should give you the desired result

```
public List<NavigationItem> GetNavigationItems(MenuType menuType, List<int> roleIds)
{
    var navigationItems = DbContext.NavigationItems
                                        .Where(x => x.MenuTypeId == (int) menuType && 
                                                !x.IsDeleted && 
                                                x.NavigationItemsPermissions.Any(r => roleIds.Contains(r.RoleId)));
    return navigationItems;
}
```

**Edit**

If you *" only need NavigationItemsPermissions where NavigationItemsPermissions.RoleId is in roleIds"*, you can use this query

```
var navigationPermissions = DbContext.NavigationItems
                                    .Where(x => x.MenuTypeId == (int) menuType && 
                                            !x.IsDeleted)
                                    .SelectMany(ni => ni.NavigationItemsPermissions)
                                    .Where(np => roleIds.Contains(np.RoleId))
                                    .ToList();
```

Use `Distinct()` before `ToList()` if there are repeated items and you want only distinct items.

**Edit 2**

```
var navigationItems = DbContext.NavigationItems
                                    .Where(x => x.MenuTypeId == (int) menuType && 
                                            !x.IsDeleted && 
                                            x.NavigationItemsPermissions.Any(r => roleIds.Contains(r.RoleId)));     
navigationItems.ForEach(x => x.NavigationItemsPermissions = x.NavigationItemsPermissions.Where(r => roleIds.Contains(r.RoleId)).ToList());
```

Comment: Thank you, i was doing check wrong the whole time. ;)

Comment: Ah, seems like i am getting everything back and not just roleIds that i want, any input?

Comment: `x.NavigationItemsPermissions.Any(r => roleIds.Contains(r.RoleId))` gives you all those `NavigationItems` where **Any** of the `NavigationItemsPermissions` is in `roleIds`. Do you want `NavigationItems` where **All** `NavigationItemsPermissions` are in `roleIds` ?

Comment: I need all NavigationItems the way they are filtered at the moment, but i only need NavigationItemsPermissions where NavigationItemsPermissions.RoleId is in roleIds

Comment: I've added additional images to post, hope it helps

Comment: Though I'm still not certain what exactly you are expecting here, see if the edited answer helps you?

Comment: From what i see this will give me only NavigationItemsPermissions  but not the NavigationItems. I need to mantain this object structire (see first post, last image). Your first solution is what i need but without NavigationItemsPermissions that are not in roleIds. Let's say my menuType = 1 and roleIds = {1,3}, For NavigationItem with Id = 1 i need to get NavigationItemsPermissions with Id 1, 7 and 9

Comment: If I understood the requirement, Edit-2 should work for you. Please check.

Answer (score 3):

you can use `contains` in this case

```
public List<NavigationItem> GetNavigationItems(MenuType menuType, List<int> roleIds)
    {
        var navigationItems = DbContext.NavigationItems.Where(x => x.MenuTypeId == (int) menuType && !x.IsDeleted && roleIds.contains(x.RoleId)));


        return navigationItems;
    }
```

Comment: This wont work since x.RoleId is in NavigationItemsPermissions and not in NavigationItem